# SQL DATEPART without creating a new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2012, datepart

I wish to be able to be able to do something like this for use with @YearVar later.

```
SET @YearVar DATETIME = CONVERT(nvarchar, date_hired, 106),
DATEPART(YEAR, date_hired)
```

However the only way I know how to datepart is like this :

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar, date_hired, 106) As Hire_Date,
DATEPART(DAY, date_hired) As [Day],
DATEPART(MONTH, date_hired) As [Month],
DATEPART(YEAR, date_hired) AS [Year]
FROM hire
```

Any help would be great thanks.

Andy

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to achive,, but why don't use computed columns (from the syntax I assume SQLServer)?

Comment: Yup, SQL Server. I'm not using computer columns because I have no idea what that is. I want to get the year of "date_hired" and store it in a variable for use later. The only way I know is to create a new column and then go like that.

Comment: Syntax is very similar to regular column, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx , in your case it would be something like `ALTER TABLE ... ADD [DAY] as DATEPART(DAY, date_hired) `

Comment: I don't want to add a table though?

Comment: YOU CAN USE SUBSTRING THEN CAPTURE ONLY CHARACTERS YOU LIKE

Answer (score 0):

You can declare and set the variables like shown below.

```
DECLARE @YearVar int = (select DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()))
```

OR

```
DECLARE  @YearVar int    
SET @YearVar =  (select DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()))
```

The select query should return only one value.

if you want to set the value once and use it in a query as you have shown, it will always give you the same value. If you are looking to calculate year for every row in the table, the query you have shown will work. Alternatively, you can create a computed column as `ALTER TABLE hire ADD year as DATEPART(YEAR, date_hired)` but that will execute `DATEPART` for every row in the table.

Answer (score 0):

From your question and comments, you would be looking for something like:

```
DECLARE @YearHired int
SET @Year = (SELECT YEAR(date_hired) FROM hire)
```